# How to create play framework application with maven support

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlet-3.0, playframework-2.4

I want to create a play framework 2.4 application using maven and deploy it on tomcat server as a war file. i am using IntelliJ. can some one tell me the process.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin how to package play as war file.

Comment: It is just for packaging as a war. I need to create a play framework 2.4 application with maven support.

Comment: Then have a look at this https://github.com/orrsella/play-maven-integration this all examples I know which could help.

Comment: I tried it but I couldn't achieve it. Most of the pom configuration is done in scala. I am looking for Java version